# Reading route parameters?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I am new to the Angular.
Here we go:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/ru/courses/categories', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: ':l/courses/categories', component: CourseCategoriesListComponent }
];
```

Then I got something injectable, something responsible for providing correct translation:

```
@Injectable()
export class LanguageService {
  constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  private readonly map: { [languageCode: string]: (() => TranslatorBase) } = {
    ru: () => new RussianTranslagor()
  };

  getTranslatorForCurrentLanguage(callback: (translatorBase: TranslatorBase) => void): void {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
      params => {
        console.log(params);
        // HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!
        const lang = params['l'];
        if (lang) {
          callback(this.map[lang]());
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

When I run my server and get to a `localhost:xxxxx`, `queryParams` returns empty `params` object, such that **I can't read actual value of the `:l` route parameter**. Am I doing something wrong there?

UPDATE:
**I am trying to read `:l` parameter, which is short for "language". ;)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using `queryParams` instead of `params`. `queryParams` represents the query-string parameters, but your `l` parameter is just a normal parameter and so should be obtained through `params` (or `paramMap`).

Comment: Unfortunately, you seems to be wrong. Neither `params` nor `queryParams` ship any value...

Comment: That's odd - I just tested your scenario on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyqskh) and it worked when I switched from `queryParams` to simply `params`.

Comment: Might be the case that I need to establish RouterOutlet or something at a proper place? Might be scope-issues?

Comment: Done. Thanks for solution. I did not specify `router-outlet` and that's why if kept failing.